# Convert a string into a JSX Element as an object property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-conversion, jsx

I'm trying to convert a string that I get from a database into a JSX Element type in this function in React :

```
const flattenMenuItems = flattenMenu(nonContextualisedMenu)
  .filter((navItem) => navItem.url !== null)
  .map((navItem) => {
    const Element = navItem.componentName;
    return {
      path: navItem.url as string,
      element: <Element /> <= the element I want to convert into a JSX.Element
    };
  });
```

The `nonContextualisedMenu` returns an array of objects with this type :

```
export type MenuNavigation = {
  pageId: string;
  pageLabel: string;
  url?: string | null;
  order?: string | null;
  componentName?: string | null; <= here I get a string from the database
  listSubMenu: MenuNavigation[] | null;
};
```

For example, I get an array of objects like this :

```
    [
      {
        componentName: "Settings",
        listSubMenu : [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
        order: null,
        pageId: "CODM0000"
        pageLabel: "Paramètres"
        url: "/settings"
      },
      {
        ...
      }
    ]
```

When I try to render a JSX.Element based on my string, the value of `element` property returns this error :

```
const flattenMenuItems = flattenMenu(nonContextualisedMenu)
  .filter((navItem) => navItem.url !== null)
  .map((navItem) => {
    const Element = navItem.componentName;
    return {
      path: navItem.url as string,
      element: <Element /> <= Error : JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures.
    };
  });
```

Is there any solution to get the `element: <Element />` converted as a JSX.Element in the return function (and without any librairies) ?

Comment: What is `Element`? Is it a component like `React.FC`? In some instance you could simply use `element: Element` instead of `element: <Element />` as that would allow whatever code is calling upon `element` to render it later

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `Element` is a const that I declare in the map but it returns a string, so if I write `element: Element`, it will remain a string and not a JSX component.

Comment: I see, in that case, you could wrap it maybe? `element: () => <Element />`, or you could convert `Element` to be a JSX component, `const Element = () => <>your string</>;`?. I can't recall the exact differences between `React.Node` and `JSX.Element` but `React.Node` is much easier to work with with the types

Comment: In this case, the string should be wrapped in a fragment using curly bracket- <>{navItem.componentName}</>. In the case this field is not present you might want to handle it by providing a fallback string depending on your app logic.